# Table fills most of the page, but there is space that can be used

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting

I use a table (tabularx) which doesn't quite fill the whole page. I would like LaTex to use the space that is still avaible, but it doesn't. Has anyone a suggestion?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please specify what exactly you would like to achieve. Do you want to top align the table on the page instead of vertically centering it or do you want to increase the row heights in order to make the table fill the whole page? Additionally, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question.

Comment: that looks like the default layout for a float page `p` position on `table`  float positioning depends mostly on the text on _surrounding_ pages and there is not much that can be said with no example shown

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers!! I didn't get notified about your replies via E-Mail, that's why I'm only now reacting.. David was right, it's mostly about the surrounding text. I thought there would be a way to force LaTeX to fill the page with more sentences. I think I'm just going to leave it that way, LaTeX probably knows best what looks good... 
Thanks again for your time!!